# Requesting grandchildren from a parent with one request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have the following models

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  books: DS.hasMany('book')
});

App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  person: DS.belongsTo('person'),
  chapters: DS.hasMany('chapter', { async: true })
});

App.Chapter = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  book: DS.belongsTo('book')
});
```

I'm using the ActiveModelAdapter

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter;
```

My API sideloads book data alongside a person, so `@store.find('person', 1)` returns JSON that would look something like the following

```
{
  person: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Smith',
    book_ids: [1, 2]
  },
  books: [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Book 1',
    chapter_ids: [1, 2]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Book 2',
    chapter_ids: [3]
  }]
}
```

Given that my API is setup to accept a request that looks something like

```
/chapters?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3
```

If I have an instance of a `Person`, can I ask ember-data to fetch all of its chapters for each of its books **in a single query**, and have them accessible via the association? For example,

```
person.get('books.firstObject').get('chapters')  # or...
person.get('books')[1].get('chapters')
```

Essentially, I don't want to issue N number of requests, where N = the number of books the person has.

[Here is a jsbin I started](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xoromovayiku/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, You'd either want to send them all down with the original request, or fetch them manually and sideload them into the store.

Comment: Thanks, can you show me an example of what you mean so I can accept?

Comment: For fetching chapters manually, look into http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload. So you would make an ajax call to get the data for chapters for given person and then use pushPayload to feed them in to the store. The json structure is already provided in the example in the link.